# What font is used by the New York MoMA?

Tags: font-identification

What font is used in this logo?

[image: Logo image]

Here is logo in the footer of this [page](http://www.moma.org/#linear).

Looks a little like [URW Linear Ultra Bold](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/urw/linear/urw-linear-t-ultra-bold), but the 'A' is slightly different.

It's a very basic typeface, but I love how wide and solid it is. Also, similar fonts work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Franklin Gothic

Some history: http://www.underconsideration.com/speakup/archives/001608.html

Answer (score 3):

Actually, MoMA has their own official typeface, it is inspired by Franklin Gothic. At one point the museum used Franklin Gothic, but currently they use their own *MoMA Gothic* that was developed by their team of designers.

Comment: [citation](http://www.moma.org/explore/inside_out/2013/04/08/one-typeface-fits-all-at-moma/), if anyone is interested